# How can I use commands as \alph, \Alph and \roman?

Tags: roman

I want to use Alphabetic counter or Romanic counter, when I write Section or use theorem.

But in my tex studio, which is name of created tex program, that commands as `\alph`, `\Alph` and `\roman` are not activated.

So, Should I use new user pakage??

How can I solve this problem??

Please, help me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Post a minimal example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: For example `\renewcommand\thefigure{\alph{figure}}`, etc. You should provide more information, what you like to have. BTW, this is no mater of your TeXstudio but code of your document

Comment: I solve this problem. i didn't know i should exactly write \the~~ in second term. Really thanks to all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your `MWE`, understood that you need to change the counter of `\section`, if my understanding is correct, then try with:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}`
```

Please excuse, if my understanding is wrong...

Comment: I solve this problem by you. Really thank you.

Comment: @GJMin Thanks for your kind words...